# vimの:terminalで端末ノーマルモードから端末ジョブモードに戻る方法を教えてください。

Tags: vim

下記のterminal機能のvimのドキュメントにある通り、
terminal - Vim日本語ドキュメント https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-ja/terminal.html#Terminal-Job
:terminalを実行して、端末作業をした後、
Ctrl-W + N で端末ノーマルモードにモード変更すると、
カーソル移動やコピーなどが可能になりました。

この端末ノーマルモードから、再び端末ジョブモードに戻り、
端末の表示データを残したまま、端末作業を再開したいのですが、
なにか方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

そのドキュメントの Ctrl-W + N が書いてある10行ほど下に方法が書かれてあります。
`i` や `a` を入力します。